# Why am I getting subscript out of range UBound for this line of coding?

Tags: vba

```
'the array is from 0 till the number of sheets

Sub FilterToSheets()
  Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet
  Dim TargetSheet As Worksheet
  Dim SheetNames As Variant
  Dim i As Long
  Dim LR As Long

  Set SourceSheet = Sheets("Yield - Weekly.rdl") 'the name of sheet that contains the data
  SheetNames = Array("MV1", "MV2", "DA1", "F1", "SF1") 'the name categories in the table to be separate according to this sheets

  Const FilterColumn = 7 'the number of column

  'from the source sheet
  With SourceSheet
    LR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'array loops from 0

    For i = 0 To UBound(SheetNames)
      Set TargetSheet = Worksheets(SheetNames(i))
      TargetSheet.Cells.ClearContents
      'starts from the range a5 till R
      With .Range("A5:R" & LR)
        .AutoFilter Field:=FilterColumn, Criteria1:=SheetNames(i)
        .Offset(0, 0).Copy TargetSheet.Range("A5")
      End With
      'continue to next loop
    Next i
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this error.  Code runs just fine in the sample data I cooked up.  The indexing of the array is correct, it holds elements 0,1,2,3,4 and iterates across them just fine, and exits when you'd expect it to (in Excel 2013 anyway)?

Comment: You never tell on which line the error occurs. It can be `Worksheets(SheetNames(i))` if that sheet does not exist or at `SheetNames(i)` if you are using `option base 1`.